# Windows 10 flicker in WPF App

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, windows-10, flicker

I have a `WPF` app which was working on pre Windows 10 OSs properly.
Now on Windows 10, on **Lenovo Lavie Z**, the app flickers a single fast flash in almost 5 minutes interval.
I updated display driver to latest, no change.
Other apps are working properly, but just this WPF app is flickering.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable double buffering. I know this from using several different applications that have it enabled to prevent the flashing you're talking about...unfortunately I don't know how to implement it.